# CloudWatch event is not triggering for S3 PutObject event when file size is above ~15MB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a CloudWatch which has to capture all the PutObject events and process based on the filetype by logging the event into loggroup. based on the filetype a particular lambda function is triggered process the file.
I am able to trigger lambda as expected only when file size is less than 15MB. When file size is more than 15MB neither cloudwatch event is logging the information nor lambda is triggering(I am using S3 trigger in Lambda function).

Comment: could you please share your s3 bucket configuration? S3 event triggers, are triggered even with 0kb size s3 objects so i imagine your issue is related to your configuration. If you can share more details maybe i can help further :)

Answer (score 1):

This is possibly because the object was uploaded via [Amazon S3 Multi-part Upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html).

In the S3 Event configuration, also activate `Multipart upload completed` and the Lambda function should be triggered when the file is uploaded via multi-part upload.